# Oracle - ORA-01848 error

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to execute the following query

```
SELECT w.grid_no, SUM(A) 
FROM TABLE_1 w 
WHERE w.DAY between to_date((select jsow from TABLE_2 t where t.grid_no = w.grid_no and t.crop_no=90) || '-2016','DDD-YYYY') - 0 
      and to_date((select jsow from TABLE_2 t where t.grid_no = w.grid_no and t.crop_no=90) || '-2016','DDD-YYYY') + 0 + 10 - 1 
      and A > 8 
group BY w.GRID_NO
```

but I have the error

```
01848. 00000 -  "day of year must be between 1 and 365 (366 for leap year)"
```

Conversely, if I add a filter on grid_no the query works; e.g.

```
SELECT w.grid_no, SUM(A) 
FROM TABLE_1 w 
WHERE w.grid_no=1000  -- <---- the added filter
      and w.DAY between to_date((select jsow from TABLE_2 t where t.grid_no = w.grid_no and t.crop_no=90) || '-2016','DDD-YYYY') - 0 
      and to_date((select jsow from TABLE_2 t where t.grid_no = w.grid_no and t.crop_no=90) || '-2016','DDD-YYYY') + 0 + 10 - 1 
     and A > 8
```

The two tables involved are:

```
TABLE_1 [grid_no, day, A]
TABLE_2 [grid_no, crop_no, jsow]
```

jsow is a Julian day: for a given pair (grid_no, crop_no) the maximum value stored in table 2 can go from 1 to 366.

My goal is to have something like that: for each grid_no in TABLE_1, I have to get the corresponding jsow value in TABLE_2 and sum the A values in the range specified via jsow.

Comment: The error suggests you actually have `jsow` values that are not between 1 and 366?

Comment: @AlexPoole I checked that: MIN(jsow)=1, MAX(jsow)=366. grid_id = 1000 (see second query) have jsow=366

Comment: Grid ID 1000 clearly has OK jsow values, It's one of the others that doesn't. Are you saying `select min(jsow), max(jsow) from table_2` shows 1 and 366 across *all* grid IDs, or just for 1000? If it does for all IDs, is that both with and without the `crop_no = 90` filter?

Comment: @AlexPoole jsow = 366 with crop_no = 90 and grid_id = 1000

Comment: Do you have null values for jsow, for crop 90? Or grid IDs in table 1 that don't have any matching rows in table 2 for crop 90?

Comment: No null values in tha table. 366 should work since 2016 is a leap year. I don't understand what is the problem

Comment: I also tried this: WHERE w.grid_no IN (select grid_no from jsow) to make sure all grid_id's have a matching. I'm trying adding 'and crop_no=90'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have null values in `table_2`, or have a `grid_id` in `table_1` which has no matching rows in `table_2` (for crop 90), the subquery will either return null or no data. Either way , you end up with an invalid data string.

With some dummy data:

```
create table table_1 (grid_no, day, a) as
  select 1000, date '2016-01-01', 42 from dual
  union all select 1001, date '2016-01-02', 42 from dual
  union all select 1002, date '2016-01-03', 42 from dual
  union all select 1003, date '2016-01-04', 42 from dual;

create table table_2(grid_no, crop_no, jsow) as
  select 1000, 90, 1 from dual
  union all select 1001, 91, 367 from dual
  union all select 1002, 90, null from dual;

SELECT w.grid_no,
  (select jsow from TABLE_2 t where t.grid_no = w.grid_no and t.crop_no=90) as jsow,
  (select jsow from TABLE_2 t where t.grid_no = w.grid_no and t.crop_no=90) || '-2016' as date_string
FROM TABLE_1 w;

   GRID_NO       JSOW DATE_STRING                                  
---------- ---------- ---------------------------------------------
      1000          1 1-2016                                       
      1001            -2016                                        
      1002            -2016                                        
      1003            -2016
```

If you try to convert one of those `'-2016` strings to a date you'll get the same error:

```
select to_date('-2016', 'DDD-YYYY') from dual;

ORA-01848: day of year must be between 1 and 365 (366 for leap year)
```

You can rewrite your query with a join instead of two subqueries, which makes it slightly easier to filter the rows you want:

```
SELECT w.grid_no, SUM(w.A) 
FROM TABLE_1 w 
JOIN TABLE_2 t ON t.grid_no = w.grid_no
AND w.DAY between to_date(t.jsow || '-2016','DDD-YYYY') - 0
  AND to_date(t.jsow || '-2016','DDD-YYYY') + 9
WHERE t.crop_no=90
AND t.jsow between 1 and 366
AND w.A > 8
GROUP BY w.GRID_NO;
```

The inner join means any `table_1` rows without `table_2` rows are ignored; the filter on `jsow` is in case there are matches that are null. You might prefer that to become an outer join depending on what else you are really doing.